# Use jQuery Inputmask that allows only A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and spaces

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I use Robin Herbots jQuery.Inputmask to restrict what my users are allowed to enter into textboxes, I've found that this jQuery plugin works rather well.  I have a textbox on my form that I want to be able to restrict the input to only characters A-Z (upper and lowercase), spaces, and numbers.  The documentation, located [here](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/), doesn't address this particular case and nothing I've attempted works neither does anything I've found online.  My textbox code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=TextBox_DataFieldTitle.ClientID%>").inputmask("******************");
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `regex` property:

```js
$("#in").inputmask({regex: "(\\w| )*"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/5.0.8/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>

<input id="in">
```

Side note: this library has an issue: it doesn't respond well to combination keys, like the `¨` key I have on my keyboard, which is intended to be combined with the next key stroke, like `e` in order to type `ë`.